# Convert a python script into executable file

Tags: python-2.7

Everyone!
I create a Small script in Python version 2.7 and build a .exe file using py2exe.
It  works fine, (I Also including raw_input() at the end of script so that, c-prompt screen wait till , hit a enter)
But, when I copy the dist folder including my .exe file on other computer , on lauching the file, It quickly load_up and exit automatically in a flash ....
don't know what to do to make it ok. 
Need help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have faced the same problem. When you convert .py to .exe there are also created some folder and files named "dist" and many more. So if you only copy .exe to another PC it will not run. you have to copy all relevent folder to run that script.

If persist then run that exe file by cmd prompt. Then you will see the error.

Comment: I appreciate that man, Actually I Do copy That Whole Relevant Folder, And It work,but the Problem is the C-prompt window Does appears for less than a second... That's the problem , I am can't able to use that!

Comment: If persist then run that exe file by cmd prompt. Then you will see the error.

Comment: if you run that from cmd you will see the error. let me inform about that.